# Working with MySQL booleans in python

Tags: python, mysql, boolean

I am querying a MySQL database in python and selecting a boolean value -- so the response from MySQL is either the string 'True' or 'False'. I would like to execute further code based on the boolean value from MySQL.

E.g.

```
data = 'False'  # assume this is what was returned by MySQL.
if data:
  print 'Success'  #really this would be where I would execute other if True.
else:
  print 'Fail'  #really this would be where I would execute other code if False
```

But I can't do this because

```
if data:
```

will always return True

So how do I convert the string that MySQL is returning into a boolean in python?

Currently I have:

```
data = 'False'  # assume this is what was returned by MySQL.
if data == 'True':
  print 'Success'
else:
  print 'Fail'
```

I believe there must be a better way to do this in python -- likely there is something simple I am missing.

Answer (score 3):

Boolean in MySQL is TINYINT(1). Checking for 1 or 0 might work

Comment: Thanks!. I am not sure how that would work though. Specifically MySQL is currently returning True or False. Is there a way I can cast it into an Int? Here is a sample SQL query SELECT IsRegistered FROM Users WHERE email = "email@email.com";  That returns True or False. How can I cast it to an int?

Comment: You can fetch a single row to check whether the query returns an empty set or now.

Executing and fetching the value of "SELECT FOUND_ROWS()" right after the original SELECT should also work.

Answer (score 2):

If the column is always one of the actual strings `"False"` or `"True"` (as opposed to integers or something) then I'd recommend some variation on:

```
value = {'False' : False, 'True' : True}[data]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find the place MySQLDdb converts the values in the converters.py file in the MySQLdb directory.

here's the snippet dealing with bool:

```
conversions = {
    ...
    types.BooleanType: Bool2Str,
    ...
}
```

And the Bool2Str function:

```
def Bool2Str(s, d): return str(int(s))
```

If you want different behavior, import the conversions dict and change it.

Answer (score 1):

If your db connection doesn't know how to transform the values for you, then you need to use a better one. This should not be something you need to do yourself. If these are not actual booleans, but just an int column you only store 0 or 1 in, then you should fix your schema. Alternatively, if you always get the values 'True' and 'False', maybe you are accidentally converting it to a string somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ord` which return an integer representing the Unicode.

Example:

```
if ord(data):
    print("True")

if not ord(data):
    print("False")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is actually quite OK, but there are alternatives:

If you are using Python 2.5 or higher, you can shorten the if statement:

```
print 'Success' if data == 'True' else 'Fail'
```

If you are finding yourself repeating the check often, you might consider writing a function for it to make it more readable:

```
def is_true(mysql_boolean):
    if mysql_boolean == "True":
        return True
    else:
        return False

# now you can use this:
if is_true(data):
    # this is really going to be more than one line of code anyway.
    # or maybe a function call, in which your solution might be enough.
    print "Success"
else:
    print "Fail"
```

You can achieve the same thing with a dictionary, but I don't find this as elegant:

```
mysql_bool = {'True': True, 'False': False}

if mysql_bool[data]:
    print "Success"
```

That said, what are you using to connect to the DB? There is probably a way to directly get a bool out of there. Please update your Question!

Answer (score 0):

This handles the way it's returned by MySQLdb.

```
if data == '\x01':
  print 'Success'
else:
  print 'Fail'
```

Verified this works for Python 3.6

```
if data == b'\x01':
  print('Success')
else:
  print('Fail')
```